# convert ByteString to Json using java

Tags: java, json, java-8, akka-http

I am getting response from Rest as :

```
{"id":81236,"root":0,"child":3,"branch":0,"results":[{"message":"valid"},{"message":"valid"}}
```

I want to convert it into JsonObject using java 8.

**I am trying JsonObject but i stucked with the POJO , because Json response may have some additional field sometimes.**

So i want to be generic so that any valid json in form of ByteString can be easily converted to JSonObject.

Comment: post code which you have tried.

Comment: There is an error in your json. It is not valid json

Comment: response Json is invalid. ']' is missing

Comment: by ByteString what do you mean?? a string of bytes or google protobuf's ByteString??

Comment: {"id":81236,"root":0,"child":3,"branch":0,"results":[{"message":"valid"},{"message":"valid"}]} ... here is valid json now

Comment: JSONObject json = new JSONObject("{\"id\":81236,\"root\":0,\"child\":3,\"branch\":0,\"results\":[{\"message\":\"valid\"},{\"message\":\"valid\"}]} ")......................................................but it requires map<String,Object>

Comment: If you're talking about `javax.json.JsonObject`, then what does that have to do with POJO?

Comment: @avy Your comment is using `JSONObject`, question is using `JsonObject`.

Comment: My json format is not fixed ...it could have any no. of attributes in it...... i need solution for how to convert this plain test into json

Comment: I was trying different possiblities to convert it into Json.

Comment: Are you using `javax.json.JsonObject`, `com.google.gson.JsonObject`, `net.sf.json.JSONObject`, `org.json.JSONObject`, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using `org.json.JSONObject`, the below works fine...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "{\"id\":81236,\"root\":0,\"child\":3,\"branch\":0,\"results\":[{\"message\":\"valid\"},{\"message\":\"valid\"}]}";
        JSONObject objJsonObject = new JSONObject(test);
        System.out.println(objJsonObject);
}
```

- **As pointed out by @Andreas it is not possible for designing a POJO class for a dynamic json object.**

Comment: Unlikely if OP is stuck on POJOs, since your code doesn't use POJOs.

Comment: @Andreas since OP mentions that his input json is not fixed there is no point in using a POJO. i see this approach as the simplest.

Comment: So you should *explain* that POJOs are not good for dynamic JSON.

Comment: @Andreas thanks for improving my answer. i will modify my answer accordingly. :)